# Solving simultaneous equations of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: MATRIX EQUATION]
so the question which is written in swedish states the following, given that all the varibles in the simoultanous equation are MATRICES of size 2*2 and B is given to be (2 1 1 1) (idk how to insert matrices here ) solve the system of equations. again X and  Y are matrices and so is B, E is the identity matrix I thats how its referred to it in most Scandinavia, yea i know S T U P I D! but we'll have to live with it.

I searched all over the internet and didn't find anything related to system of matrix equations. and when i say i search all over the internet i mean it, i mean i went from google p 1 to p19 and didn't find anything about PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following equations, where $\{B,E,X,Y\}$ are matrices, 
$$BX+Y=B$$
$$X+BY=B+2E.$$
Subtract the $B \times$ bottom row from the top to get:

$$BX+Y=B$$
$$-(BX+B\cdot BY=B\cdot B+2EB)$$
$$-------------$$
$$Y-B\cdot BY=B-B\cdot B -2EB$$
$$\implies (E-B\cdot B)Y=(-E-B)B$$
You can show that the determinant of matrix $(E-B\cdot B) \ne 0,$ implying that the matrix is invertible, or that $(E-B\cdot B)^{-1}$ exists. Thus,
$$(E-B\cdot B)^{-1}(E-B\cdot B)Y=(E-B\cdot B)^{-1}(-E-B)B$$
$$Y=(E-B\cdot B)^{-1}(-E-B)B$$
The righthand side is pretty straightforward to compute, especially for $2 \times 2$ matrices. Once you find the value of $Y$, you can solve for $X$ pretty easily:
$$BX=B-Y$$
$$B^{-1}\cdot BX=B^{-1}\cdot (B-Y),$$
...since, as you know, $B$ is invertible, and thus, 
$$X=B^{-1}\cdot (B-Y).$$

It is just easier to compute $X$ accordingly:
$$X=B+2E−BY.$$

Comment: Once $Y$ is known, it is even faster to find $X$ as $X=B+2E-BY$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah, I just wanted to highlight that $B$ was invertible- sounds like Reddevil is learning linear algebra for the first time, and I'm hoping this exercise helps him get familiar with the works. I can append my answer to include the easiest way to find $X$.

Comment: Hello @HenningMakholm thank you so much for taking the time to solve my problem. However there is something stroke me as odd when when you did the factorisation, as far as i am concerned matrices division is undefined, however you took B out of the braket and left a 1 instead of it as if you were dividing by B shouldn't you've left "I" instead  B(1−B−2E)?

Comment: @daOnlyBG: It looks like you have an error in the line starting with $\implies$. When you extract the common factors of $Y$ and $B$ you need to preserve which side they're on, so the conclusion should be $(E-BB)Y=(E-B-2E)B$ instead of what you write, and this error propagates throughout the solution. This is not important on the left-hand side (everything there happens to commute), but on the right-hand side it is.

Comment: Good eye, @HenningMakholm. Let me take care of that, sorry for the sloppiness.

Comment: i guess i have mixed you guys up i thought that @ HenningMakholm was the one who answered my question, and @daOnlyBG was just a commenter! sorry! and thank you a lot both of you! :)

Comment: @Reddevil no worries