# Question about an equationsystem of marices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

My problem is the exact same as this one:

[Solving simultaneous equations of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162618/solving-simultaneous-equations-of-matrices/1162644)

In the solution the following happens

$$-(BX+B\cdot BY=B\cdot B+2EB)$$
$$-->$$
$$Y-B\cdot BY=B-B\cdot B -2EB$$

My question is what happens here?

Comment: That person was subtracting $B$ times the second equation from the first equation to get the resulting equation. (First and second equations from the given system of equations.)

Comment: I see. Thank you!